# Sphinx - images in PDF

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx

I am using Sphinx to document a project. I'd like to produce HTML and PDF formats. I’ve used rinohtype to export PDF, which works well. However, images are consistently rendered wider than the page width. Is there a way to configure image width for the entire document, rather than for each image individually?

I’ve tried playing with Latex preamble, but no success so far. This is the Latex preamble I've placed into Sphinx' `conf.py`:

```
latex_elements = {
    # The paper size ('letterpaper' or 'a4paper').
    #
    'papersize': 'a4paper',

    # The font size ('10pt', '11pt' or '12pt').
    'pointsize': '10pt',
    
    # Latex preamble
    'preamble': '\usepackage{graphicx}\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}',

    # Latex figure (float) alignment
    'figure_align': 'htbp',
    'pxunit': '300px=1in',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question whether you are using the LaTeX Sphinx builder or the one provided by rinohtype. If you are using the rinohtype builder, the settings in `latex_elements` (except for *papersize*) will not have any effect.

Since rinohtype 0.2.1, images should automatically be scaled down to fit within the available text width. If that is not the case for your document, please [file a bug report](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/issues/new/choose).